# Oracle SQL Calculate growth value from ONE column

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to calculate

INCOME_growth = INCOME_YTD - Income_prv_Month

I tried lag function, self join I couldn't get it to work

Example (starting point) table_employee_info:

```
| Date        |Employee_NO|INCOME_YTD  |Date_ID|
---           |---        |---         |---    |
| 1/31/2022   |1002       |50          |202230
| 2/28/2022   |1045       |80          |202260
| 3/31/2022   |F104       |40          |202290
| 1/31/2022   |1002       |30          |202230
| 2/28/2022   |1045       |90          |202260
| 3/31/2022   |F104       |100         |202290
| 1/31/2022   |1002       |65          |202230
| 2/28/2022   |1045       |60          |202260
| 3/31/2022   |F104       |200         |202290
```

The desired result will look like this:
first, we will need to order by Employee_NO then Date.
second, calculate new column Income_prv_Month.
third, calculate another column  INCOME_growth.

```
| Date        |Employee_NO|INCOME_YTD  |Income_prv_Month|INCOME_growth|Date_ID|
---           |---        |---         |---             |---         |---   
| 1/31/2022   |1002       |50          |0               |50          |202230
| 1/31/2022   |1002       |30          |50              |-20         |202230
| 1/31/2022   |1002       |65          |30              |30          |202230
| 2/28/2022   |1045       |80          |0               |80          |202260
| 2/28/2022   |1045       |90          |80              |10          |202260
| 2/28/2022   |1045       |60          |90              |-30         |202260
| 3/31/2022   |F104       |40          |0               |40          |202290  
| 3/31/2022   |F104       |100         |40              |60          |202290
| 3/31/2022   |F104       |200         |100             |100         |202290
```

I will be grateful for any tips or help

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there any column that can represent your order `Date` column seems like can't do that because that is same as same grouping

Comment: You don't need to **order** by employee_no first; you must **partition** by employee, and then, within each partition, you need to **order** by date. Aside from that: your sample output is wrong - the dates are wrong. You show only January for the first employee (on all three of his rows), etc. You may want to edit to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try to use `LAG` window function but the real problem is there might not be a column that can represent your order of expected results as I comment, if there is a column we can replace as my below query `[column which represnt your expect order]` part

```
SELECT t1.*,
       LAG(INCOME_YTD,1,0) OVER(PARTITION BY Employee_NO ORDER BY date_ID ) Income_prv_Month,
       INCOME_YTD - LAG(INCOME_YTD,1,0) OVER(PARTITION BY Employee_NO ORDER BY date_ID ) INCOME_growth
FROM T t1
```

Comment: I have added date_ID to order the dates

Comment: @PyD I had updated my query you can try that, but your `date_ID ` has the same value in the same grouping... if `date_ID `  can represent the order my query might be worked.

Comment: @PyD Here is a sample for you https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=78e8e2b34c8db44d14c56ee2f0b02862